# I can use XAML Islands in WPF just if the .NET Core is the target platform?

Tags: wpf, windows-community-toolkit, xaml-islands

I'd like to use `XAML Islands` in my WPF project, which targets .NET Framework. I tried to add to my project, but I couldn't make it work. [This](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/) article says that the WPF apps are supported, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands#limitations) says that:

> Using XAML Islands to host WinRT XAML controls is supported only in WPF and Windows Forms apps that target .NET Core 3.x. XAML Islands **are not supported in apps that target the .NET Framework**.

This means that the only thing what I can do is to migrate my project from .NET Framework to .NET Core? This would be a huge work... Do I have any other possibilities to use the `XAML Islands`?

Comment: I would take a look at upgrading to .net 5. Release candidates are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You must migrate to .NET Core / .NET 5 in order to use XAML Islands.

Depending on your app and what third-party dependencies you have, migrating can be pretty simple.

Comment: I think Xaml Islands is only supported in .NET Core 3.X. As of today is not supported in .NET 5.

Comment: Not supported in Net 5 June'21. From the Microsoft documentation "Using XAML Islands to host WinRT XAML controls in WPF and Windows Forms apps is currently supported only in apps that target .NET Core 3.x. XAML Islands are not yet supported in apps that target .NET 5, or in apps that any version of the .NET Framework"

Comment: So, in .NET 5 and above, what the Microsoft suggests to use instead of Xaml Islands?